# MongoDB C driver gives strange error about OpenSSL while installing

Tags: mongodb, cmake, openssl, mongo-c-driver

While I'm trying to install MongoDB C driver via CMake, at compilation process it gives error that says;

- `libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0: undefined reference to "OSSL_HTTP_parse_url"`
- `libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0: undefined reference to "SSL_get1_peer_certificate"`

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and my OpenSSL version is `OpenSSL 1.1.1f` which Ubuntu says latest. I followed directions on [MongoDB's official C driver setup](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html). If somehow my OpenSSL packages broken, how can I fix it?

When I try it with an Ubuntu 20.04 image from Docker and running it on a container, I can compile it fine with the same OpenSSL package.

Comment: `apt-get install libmongoc-1.0-0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why exactly but executing cmake configuration part that is on the website (`cmake -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF ..`) with `sudo` solved this. Maybe it made CMake to find the right version of OpenSSL. I didn't perform any update on OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

The general advice is: whenever possible, stick with the defaults (`apt-get install libmongoc-1.0-0`).

Not sure what / how you're trying to build, but according to [[OpenSSL]: SSL_get1_peer_certificate](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_get1_peer_certificate.html) (**emphasis** is mine):

> SSL_get0_peer_certificate() and **SSL_get1_peer_certificate() were added in 3.0.0**. SSL_get_peer_certificate() was deprecated in 3.0.0.

Same thing about *OSSL_HTTP_parse_url*.

So, you need (newer) ***OpenSSL 3.0*** (don't know why this isn't specified in the installation *URL*). 
Most likely you'd have to build it yourself ([[OpenSSL.Wiki]: Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation)) - make sure to set ***--prefix=%OPENSSL30_INSTALL_DIR%*** and pass it (*%OPENSSL30_INSTALL_DIR%*) to (*libmongoc*'s) *configure* tool.

Comment: I thought about that too but then why it works just fine on an Ubuntu 20.04 docker container where I applied same commands.

Comment: Should be a version mismatch. Either the container has *OpenSSL 3.0*, or you're building an older *libmongoc* version (compatible with *OpenSSL 1.1.1\**).